# Extracting data from XML in parallel using R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have to process millions of xml files every week and I use a server that has 32 cores.  I run R on Ubuntu 14.04.   My current program extracts data using a for loop from these files and saves the output to MySQL. Since the processing is quite slow, I tried to parse data from xml in parallel.  The following are my codes so far:

```
//Function to parse data from xml

parse_xml <-function(FileName) {
  xmldata <- xmlParse(FileName)
  result_nodes = XML::getNodeSet(xmldata , "//IOTModellerLog/Event")
  if (!length(result_nodes)==0){
    abc <- rbindlist(lapply(result_nodes,function(x) data.frame(as.list(unlist(xmlToList(x))))),use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE) 

....do other calculations....

    abc <- data.frame(lapply(abc, as.character), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)   
  }
}
```

//Function to merge two dataframes with NA fills for non matching columns

```
sbind = function(x, y, fill=NA) {
  sbind.fill = function(d, cols){ 
    for(c in cols)
      d[[c]] = fill
    d
  }
  x = sbind.fill(x, setdiff(names(y),names(x)))
  y = sbind.fill(y, setdiff(names(x),names(y)))

  rbind(x, y)
}
```

Path to all the xml files

```
path <- "/home/mycomp/Documents/xmls/xmlfrommtar"
```

Function to parsexml.

```
workerFunc <- function(file) {
    dat <- parse_xml(file)
      df <- sbind(df,dat)
    }
```

Codes for parallel processing

```
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
files <- dir(path, pattern="*.xml|*.XML", full.names = T)
part <- clusterSplit(cl, seq_along(files))
filesPart <- lapply(part, function(p) files[p])
results <- clusterApply(cl, filesPart, workerFunc)
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  4 nodes produced errors; first error: could not find function "parse_xml"
```

This indicates two things to me, the files are getting distributed across all 4 cores of my machine.  The function clusterApply could not find parse_xml from within `workerFunc`.  However, I pretty much have the parse_xml file in my environment.

Sample XML data

```
IOTModellerLog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" DeviceID="7430180" ClientID="12324" FileCreationDate="2017-03-01T22:40:03" FileVersion="2" EventClassID="65535" IOTLogCreationDate="2017-03-01T12:29:54" SampleID="1" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="/opt/nds/ams_proxy/webapps/ams_proxy/WEB-INF/amsXmlSchema.xsd">
   <Event EventTime="2017-02-27T18:33:58">
      <IOTEvent State="PowerOn" />
   </Event>
   <Event EventTime="2017-02-28T08:59:03">
      <DataEvent>
         <Model>1</Model>
         <DataType>1</DataType>
         <DataValue>0301</DataValue>
      </DataEvent>
   </Event>
   <Event EventTime="2017-02-28T08:59:13">
      <DataEvent>
         <Model>1</Model>
         <DataType>1</DataType>
         <DataValue>0401</DataValue>
      </DataEvent>
   </Event>
</IOTModellerLog>
```

Comment: I think you would need to export the functions to multiple cores using `clusterExport`.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your cluster workers with something like:

```
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(XML))
clusterExport(cl, c('parse_xml', 'sbind'))
```